# google_maps_flutter custom markers by RepainBoundary does not move from StreamBuildeer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am fetching Latitudes and Longitude from cloud firestore and than i am converting those into custom markers. Than I am passing those markers into google maps Widget. Everything is working fine and I am receiving new location changes through StreamBuilder but the problem is that the marker is not changing its position and its static.

I have used a Stack in which I have used RepaintBoundary along with GoogleMaps:

```
 class MyGoogleMap extends StatefulWidget {
  MyGoogleMap({
    super.key,
    required this.data,
    required this.initialPositin,
    // required this.markers,
  });
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data;
  LatLng initialPositin;


  @override
  State<MyGoogleMap> createState() => _MyGoogleMapState();
}

class _MyGoogleMapState extends State<MyGoogleMap> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((a) {
      onBuildCompleted();
    });

    super.initState();
  }
  bool isLoading = false;
  final List<Marker> markers=[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(-context.h, -context.w),
          child:
        ListView(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < widget.data.length; i++)
              RepaintBoundary(
                key: widget.data[i]['key'],
                child: widget.data[i]['widget'],
              )
          ],
        ),
        ),
        isLoading
            ? Positioned.fill(
                child: GoogleMap(
                  zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: widget.initialPositin,
                    zoom: 1,
                  ),
                  markers: Set.from(markers),
                ),
              )
            : const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ],
    );
  }
  Future<void> onBuildCompleted() async {
    await Future.forEach(widget.data, (c) async {
      Marker m = await _generateMarkerFromWidget(c);

      markers.add(m);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<Marker> _generateMarkerFromWidget(Map<String, dynamic> a) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        a['key'].currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 4.0);
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(a['id']),
        position: a['position'],
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List()));
  }
}
```

And I am passing the custom widget and global key to the above widget.

```
 StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('markers').snapshots(),
              builder: (a, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return LoadingWidget(); // Show loading indicator
                } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return const LoadingWidget();
                } else {
                  List<Marker> m = [];
                  snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((element) {
                    m.add(Marker(
                        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: element.get('user')),
                        markerId: MarkerId(element.id),
                        position:
                            LatLng(element.get('lat'), element.get('lan'))));
                  });
                  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [];
                  snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
                    log(doc.data().toString(), name: "snap");
                    data.add({
                      'id': doc.id,
                      'key': GlobalKey(),
                      'widget': MyMarker(text: doc.get('user')),
                      'position': LatLng(doc.get('lat'), doc.get('lan'))
                    });
                  });

                  return MyGoogleMap(
                    data: data,
                    initialPositin: LatLng(snapshot.data!.docs.first.get('lat'),
                        snapshot.data!.docs.first.get('lan')),
                  );
                }
              })
```

Here is the marker widget:

```
class MyMarker extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMarker({super.key, required this.text});
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(context.w / 100),
            child: Text(this.text),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: context.h/100,),
        Icon(
          Icons.location_on,
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```